# Using $(OutDir) in Visual Studio .rc file

Tags: c++, visual-studio, embedded-resource

In a Visual Studio C++ project’s `.rc` file, there are two included assemblies with sources specified using relative paths. Instead I’d like to specify these relative to the output directory.

Here’s what I’m starting with:

```
#ifndef APSTUDIO_INVOKED
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//
// Generated from the TEXTINCLUDE 3 resource.
//
LANGUAGE LANG_NEUTRAL, SUBLANG_NEUTRAL
#ifdef _DEBUG
EXCELDNA.LOADER         ASSEMBLY                "..\\ExcelDna.Loader\\bin\\Debug\\ExcelDna.Loader.dll"
EXCELDNA.INTEGRATION    ASSEMBLY                "..\\ExcelDna.Integration\\bin\\Debug\\ExcelDna.Integration.dll"
#else
EXCELDNA.LOADER         ASSEMBLY                "..\\ExcelDna.Loader\\bin\\Release\\ExcelDna.Loader.dll"
EXCELDNA.INTEGRATION    ASSEMBLY                "..\\ExcelDna.Integration\\bin\\Release\\ExcelDna.Integration.dll"
#endif

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
#endif    // not APSTUDIO_INVOKED
```

I’ve tried defining macros under Properties → C/C++ → Preprocessor that reference `$(OutDir)`:

```
EXCELDNA_INTEGRATION_PATH "$(OutDir)ExcelDna.Integration.dll"
EXCELDNA_LOADER_PATH "$(OutDir)ExcelDna.Loader.dll"
```

And then replacing the section with this:

```
#ifndef APSTUDIO_INVOKED
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//
// Generated from the TEXTINCLUDE 3 resource.
//
LANGUAGE LANG_NEUTRAL, SUBLANG_NEUTRAL
EXCELDNA.LOADER         ASSEMBLY   EXCELDNA_LOADER_PATH
EXCELDNA.INTEGRATION    ASSEMBLY   EXCELDNA_INTEGRATION_PATH
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
#endif    // not APSTUDIO_INVOKED
```

But that just makes the compile error out:

```
Error   RC2135  file not found: EXCELDNA_INTEGRATION_PATH
Error   RC2135  file not found: EXCELDNA_LOADER_PATH
```

What is the correct way to do this? Is it even possible?

Comment: This file is not processed by the C++ compiler.  Use Project > Properties > Resources > General > Preprocessor Definitions.  That's just the first problem.  Do heed the considerable wrath meted out by anti-malware, hiding executable files in resources will give you problems two and three.  No quick fix for them, don't do it.

Comment: Still gives the same error. Ah well. I’ll keep that in mind about potential antivirus problems, but not packing these DLLs into the main `.xll` seems like a major change, and not one I’m prepared to make in a rather mature project (one that belongs to someone else, to boot!).